What is the reading list on specific topics at Crypto.SE?
A while back, I noticed on [Computer Science.SE], they have a Reference FAQ List, and I think it might be good to have one here at [Crypto.SE] as well.
Previously in this post:


Do you think it's a good idea?

If you have a "golden standard" question/answer in mind and want it to be included in the potential new list, post it here with a summarization, so that we can vote on which to include in the potential list.
2.1. I expect the proposal process to go for around 9 months(?) with a floating margin to both solicit for enough proposals, for votes to grow, and for poll of opinion to stablize.

Miscellaneous discussion.



Now that a bit over 7 months had passed, the votes to and the contents of most answers to this post had stablized, I'd like to propose new topics for discussion.

Do linked posts in the answers have good, clear, easily comprehendible articulations?
4.1. Would you consider improving the questions and answers in the linked posts?
4.2. If some post are too overly confusing to read, and isn't something that its intended audience can understand, would you find a replacement for it? Or, in rare cases remove the link?



It would be nice that was in my mind for a while, you are the first.


Yes, I'm all for it, but this needs to be a community driven process. 2. that makes sense 3. I think we can always try and see if it flies. We need subsections though (tags already would give a pretty good hint).


As it currently is we would get a mix of sections and answers, which is different from CS.SE. Also, when would the vote "close"? I don't know how CS handled this, maybe talk to them in chat?

@MaartenBodewes I haven't had an idea on when the vote would close, that can go to "miscellaneous discussion" and solid ideas can be proposed; I mean we don't necessarily have to post to answer point 2, point 3 is explicitly put there for that purpose. As for talking to CS.SE in chat, I'm not the most reputed to do so, nor am I most comfortable to either; if we're interested in how they went thru the process, I think there must be better person to do the liaison work.

Interested in doing that, but out of time.

I wish "almost" every site on the SE network had this feature. Another similar idea was implemented in Mathematica network. And to some extent, there is also this one and this which somehow serve the same purpose.

Must-knows for those attempting to design a (symmetric) cipher:

Modern ciphers are radically different from any classical-cipher

The frequency-analysis tag,

How to do a frequency analysis?

Cryptoanalysis using Frequency Analysis

Understanding the wide trail design strategy

Security importance of Key Schedule in Block Ciphers

How to determine which type of transposition cipher I have?

How can frequency analysis be applied to modern ciphers?

Why is writing your own encryption discouraged?

What are recommended, general strategies to start block-cipher design and/or analysis?



Do we have a archetypal question where the asker mistaken their self-designed stream cipher as OTP?

Getting to it...

Math Fundamentals and General Concepts:

What's a finite field?

External link explaining how does modular arithmetic work?
Standard basis representation of elements in binary field
The Extended Euclidean Algorithm (Finding Inverses in a Field)


What's an elliptic curve and how do you work with one?

Security Definitions

Easy explanation of "IND-" security notions?
What do the signature security abbreviations like EUF-CMA mean?


Security Models

Standard Model (why don't we have a tag for this yet?)
random-oracle-model
What is the "Random Oracle Model" and why is it controversial?
random oracle model vs standard model vs selective model




I know we have good writeups for these on the site. I'll search for them when I have time

I can't think of a good section to add that IND-{CPA,CCA,etc.} and {UUF,SUF,EUF}-CMA question, I think I'll rename this section a bit to incorporate those.

The one time pad (or not):-
Using $key^{th}$ multiple of $\pi$ as a one-time pad
If I am about to generate one-time pad, where should I generate my pads from?
Hash functions to generate a one-time pad
Is there a way to generate sound one-time pads out of public information?
How were one-time pads and keys historically generated?
and a succinct one liner:-
What do you call one time pad where pseudo-random numbers are used?

While seeking out for questions for (pre-quantum) public-key cryptography, I find that the questions being asked are variatiful. Askers' confusion can come from anywhere, and lack commonality.
Despite this, I believe the main cause is probably novices didn't properly grasp the purpose and meaning of public-key encryption, key exchange, digital signature, and sometimes other minor functionalities of PKC.
The few questions that I think has the widest audience are:

ECDSA vs ECIES vs ECDH
A step-by-step example of how to exploit predictable nonce in discrete-logarithm signature schemes
Why is public-key encryption so much less efficient than secret-key encryption?
What is the point of digital signatures if confidentiality is violated?
Why is asymmetric cryptography bad for huge data?
Security strength of RSA in relation with the modulus size
Can we find an archetypal textbook RSA question for here?

RSA Full-Domain Hash


Why do public keys need to be validated?
What are the differences between a digital signature, a MAC and a hash?
Digital signatures are !!NOT "encrypt" with private keys!!


Password Hashing and Key-Derivation Functions

Authorities on password hashing best practice
Key Derivation Functions vs. Password Hashing Schemes
Definition of "pepper" in hash functions
How does using salt reduce rainbow table attack?
(Well-Known) Standards: argon2 pbkdf, hkdf


NOBUS. "Nobody but us" - US intelligence policy. This calls into question/undermines everything on this site. This policy is confirmed by former NSA chief Michael Hayden, and President Obama January 2014.
To what degree; who knows? We can't make the argument that this site is only about the mathematics, as the mathematics may be broken or simply irrelevant to potential cryptographic advances/side channel attacks/ downright subversion.
Please consider before you vote: do you dislike the policy, or just disbelieve it?

I think a vast majority would prefer to read about legal aspects rather than political ones. Downvoting for now.
